# What does the notation, that is commonly used in diffusion models mean $\mathcal{N}(x_{t};\mu_{\theta},\Sigma_{\theta})$?

Tags: normal-distribution, notation

Commonly used in diffusion models (https://arxiv.org/pdf/2006.11239.pdf), what does the notation, $\mathcal{N}(x_{t};\mu_{\theta},\Sigma_{\theta})$ mean? I get the parameterized by $\mu$ and $\sigma$ part, but I'm unclear exactly on the $x_t$ part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's Gaussian $\mathcal{N}$ [probability density function](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/450211/35989) [parametrized by](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/301382/what-is-the-semicolon-notation-in-joint-probability/301384#301384) $\mu_\theta$ and $\Sigma_\theta$ evaluated at $x_t$ point.

Comment: thanks ! so in the case where $x$ is an image, what is the corresponding dimensionality of the mu and sigma ?

Comment: @bdfy I didn't read the paper but if $x_t$ has a length $k$ then the same is $\mu_\theta$ and $\Sigma_\theta$ is $k \times k$.